# How can I delete messages from group chat in Facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-groups, facebook-messenger

My friend and I chatted some personal information between us in a group chat being absent minded. So now we are stuck. We need to delete those messages permanently. So is it possible to delete the messages permanently so that no other group member can see the chats? None of us are admin of the group. So if we request the admin, can he do that (he is a *trustworthy person*)? Does he have this authority?

Comment: This is one of the reason I hate FB Messenger. It does not give enough control over your privacy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sorry to say so, but it is absolutely not possible to do that at all.

When you delete the conversation from your account, it will just go out of your view for ever, but will be available to be read by everyone else.

Answer (score 1):

If you are the creator of the group chat, you can got to your group chat conversation tab (`https://www.facebook.com/messages/<put your group chat conversation id here>`) and then got to the *Actions* drop down, select the **Delete Messages...** option, check (tick) the messages in the chat box that you want to delete & then click the **Delete** button. Then only those messages that you had selected will be deleted from the group chat & rest of the conversation between all members in the group chat will remain.

Answer (score 0):

I was just in the same situation. This is how we solved the problem:

Even though I deleted the messages and the other people hadn't seen them yet, they were still appearing on the chat for the one friend that had seen it. He then reported that individual message as spam under the option:

> Report individual messages from a hacked friend as spam and delete them.

Message was gone.

Answer (score 0):

Just go to group and select actions -->delete message.
Select the message you want to delete.

(this only deletes the message from your view, other people in the conversation can still see it on theirs)